# Copy text in an image and make a new with similiar layout/pattern/structure

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a text in a image file, that says "Forward". How can I with the same layout/pattern/structure create an additional text "Rewind". So I have two similar texts? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You would need to recreate this effect manually using Photoshop, and once you have the effect recreated you can apply it to whatever text you'd like. There simply is no way to just "pull an effect" out of an image.

Comment: Sounds hard, I thought you just could write a new text with no pattern and sample a piece and do cut/paste.

Comment: You can do something similar... I will post tutorial later when I have a little bit more time.

Comment: That is a photograph. While it may be possible to create something similar with Photoshop, it's doubtful you'll ever match it 100% unless you find the word "rewind" printed with thermal ink, scuffed up, then photographed at an angle.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to replicate the effect using layer styles. Layer styles apply textures, shadows, glows, bevels, transforms and a variety of other effects to any layer including text. Once you have a layer style close to that from your image, you will be able to apply it to any text you wish.

Here is an overview of [layer style presets or creating brand new ones](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/tools/intro-photoshop-layer-styles/) and a tutorial how to [apply a style to text](http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/photoshop-tutorials/layer-styles-in-photoshop/). It will take you maybe 20 minutes to complete so give it a go and it will give you an idea what layers styles are.

*It is useful you learn them as they are pretty heavily used in designs. If you right click a layer, you can copy layer style and paste it to another, which is key in having consistency across buttons, image filters and text elements in your designs.*

**I would suggest this:**

- Rather than trying to make 'Rewind' exactly replicate your 'Forward' text from the image (which would be hard to do 100%), I would recommend that you see the above image as 'inspiration' for the style that you will create.
- The layer style you create will be applied to both Forward and Rewind so they are both looking the same.
- Your image has a background texture and that is what you will need to start your 'inspirational journey' (replicating lol) :P ... Google 'paper texture' and click on images, then pick one high res texture that fits, which will serve as your background.
- Have a look at some existing styles that other people created. When you open them in Photoshop, they will be added to your presets. Download some free ones and see how they have been made. It is usually a combination of gradients, strokes, textures, drop shadows, bevels, which all can be seen in the Blending Options. Here are some free styles: [photoshopstyles.org](http://www.photoshopstyles.org/), [handmade paper styles](http://www.sugarhillco.com/shop/Handmade-paper-layerstyles), [deviant art gallery](http://photoshopfreebies.deviantart.com/gallery/23972794). Then experiment with blending options to match your inspirational image.
- Oh and one last thing ... Free Transform allows you to scale and skew elements. Looks like the text in your image above has been skewed, so you will too need to do that if you want to have it exactly like that. Here is some info on [Free Transform](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/photoshop-101-how-to-use-the-free-transform-tool/) if you need to look that up too.

Good luck with your experimentation, have fun! :)